# Unescape json response in REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a REST API written in C #. Method DoQuery send query to the database, and get json as response

```
public async Task<QueryResponseDto> DoQuery(string request)
{
  return await _dbConnection.QuerySingleAsync<QueryResponseDto>("select web.json_request('" + request + "') as response;",commandTimeout:600);
}
...
[HttpPost]
[Route("DoQuery")]
public async Task<string> DoQuery([FromBody] object body)
{
  var r = await _dataService.DoQuery(JsonSerializer.Serialize(body));
  return r.response;
}
```

When I run query in database, I get correct json answer like this

```
[
   {
      "contractor":{
         "ek2id":"91707d21-50f3-4aa4-8209-e80b963da99d",
         "externalids":[
            {
               "externalsource":"SBL",
               "externalid":"1-4OB8C75"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

But when I run method DoQuery from PostMan I get escaped response like this

```
"[{\"contractor\":{\"ek2id\":\"91707d21-50f3-4aa4-8209-e80b963da99d\",\"externalids\":[{\"externalsource\":\"SBL\",\"externalid\":\"1-4OB8C75\"}]}}]"
```

How can I get normal unescaped response from REST API?

Comment: You need to specify encoding options. Please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding

Answer (score 1):

When you query the database it formats the JSON for you when it displays the output. The actual value in the database could be some UTF8, or similar encoding.

If escape is causing issue you could try storing actual UTF8 value for quotes in the string. But in both the cases you need to encode the response.